# App Store Connect. Disable in-app purchases for new version of app

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have already released an application to the App Store. This current version contains an in-app purchase item to unlock premium features.

Now we made a new design for the app and want to release a new version of the app and this new build will not include any purchase options.

So now as you see I have two versions. First one provides in-app purchases and the second one doesn't.

How to disable in-app purchases for the second version of the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove in-app-purchase related code from the new version so It will not affect existing in-app-purchase in the AppStore Connect. And do not delete your in-app-purchases from the AppStore Connect so it'll work for the older version.

Answer (score 1):

In-app purchases are independent from app versions. You cannot enable/disable them in App Store Connect for specific versions. You will simply need to "hide" the purchase option directly in the app, if you want it to be available for older app versions.

If that is not the requirement, simply remove the in-app purchase from sale in App Store Connect.